# ¿Como puedo alinear un boton con el iframe de google maps?

Tags: html, css

Tengo un problema y es que como puedo alinear a la izquierda el boton de contacto y a la derecha el iframe de Google Maps de forma de que tdo alineado ya que he estado intentandolo .

Os paso el codigo

```
  <section class="contacte" id="section6">
  <form method="POST" action="contactar.php"> 
  <button type="submit"  class="button" name='env'>Contacte</button>
 
<div id="mapa">
 <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d11963.503810481645!2d2.2137249746337933!3d41.441913199422075!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x12a4bcbd124a13e7%3A0x4602182533bf5a10!2sFundaci%C3%B3%20Hospital%20de%20l&#39;Esperit%20Sant!5e0!3m2!1sca!2ses!4v1613580231213!5m2!1sca!2ses" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0;" allowfullscreen="" aria-hidden="false" tabindex="0"></iframe>
</div>
  </section>

CSS

.contacte{
    text-align: left;
    padding:0.2%;
    background-color: #2686E3;
    padding-bottom: 5%;
    
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como puedes leer [en este enlace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align), la propiedad **`text-align`** sirve para:

- Establecer la alineación horizontal del contenido de un [elemento en bloque](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements) o un *table cell box*

Con lo anterior en mente considera que al hacer: **`text-align: left;`** lo que estarías desplazando horizontalmente a la izquierda serían ambos elementos internos de la etiqueta `section`.

Sin embargo lo anterior no es lo que propiamente estamos buscando, entonces una opción es el uso del [módulo *flexbox*](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox)

Quedando de esta forma:

```html
<style>
  * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  .contacte {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
  }
  iframe {
    width: 500px;
    height: 200px;
  }
</style>

<section class="contacte" id="section6">
  <form method="POST" action="contactar.php"> 
    <button type="submit"  class="button" name='env'>Contacte</button>
  </form>
  <div id="mapa">
    <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d11963.503810481645!2d2.2137249746337933!3d41.441913199422075!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x12a4bcbd124a13e7%3A0x4602182533bf5a10!2sFundaci%C3%B3%20Hospital%20de%20l&#39;Esperit%20Sant!5e0!3m2!1sca!2ses!4v1613580231213!5m2!1sca!2ses" frameborder="0" style="border:0;" allowfullscreen="" aria-hidden="false" tabindex="0"></iframe>
  </div>
</section>
```

**Lecturas de interés**

- [Propiedad **`justify-content`**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#justify-content-property)
- [Propiedad **`align-items`**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#align-items-property)

Comment: Creo que el código queda mejor en un snippet, no se si te ha pasado por alto o había alguna buena razón –que yo no vi– para no hacerlo. Por si era la primera, edité la respuesta. Si era la segunda, por favor reviértela o dejame saber para revertirla yo mismo. Un saludo.

Comment: @jachguate te agradezco la edición, no lo coloqué como snnipet por que lo pasé por alto, gracias.